# How can I update vim in ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: vim

I have `vim version: 2:7.4.052-1ubuntu3 installed`.

How do I update to the latest version using the terminal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the latest vim updates run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pkg-vim/vim-daily
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

You should know also that the latest means not always the most stable ones.

Comment: I get error: Cannot add PPA: ''This PPA does not support focal''.

Answer (score 1):

This is the latest version available with your version of Ubuntu. If you would like to upgrade to the latest upstream version you will need to isntall it manually from the upstream sources. You can find out how to do that here: http://www.vim.org/mercurial.php

Comment: @Paranoid Panda, this is the latest version available in the repository. http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/vim-tiny